# Auto Update All Subscribers list from Filtered Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql, subscriber

I noticed unlike Standard Data Extensions, email addresses from Filtered Data Extensions are not automatically updated to All Subscribers.

Does anyone know how to make it an automatic process or how can I write a simple query to add these email addresses from my Filtered Data Extensions to the All Subscribers List?

What I am trying to do is to update any new email addresses from a filtered data extension to the All Subscribers List. Hence the columns that I am interested in are: "Email_Address__c" from "FilteredDE" as well as "SubscriberKey" and "EmailAddress" from "_subscribers".

p.s. Sorry I am quite new to SQL Query, so I will need some help to start off with the query script.

Thanks in advanced! :)

Comment: No Email Addresses are automatically updated to All Subscribers.  The best practice is to import you subscribers into your All Subscribers when you import them into your Sending Data Extension.  This ensures that the All Subscribers is kept up to date, because when sending to a Data extension, Marketing Cloud will use the All Subscribers Email Address of the subscriber if it's found, else it will use the one in the Data Extension (assuming the field is Email Address Data Type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one and only approach that is working for me is via 3 activities and an automation to run all these activities in sequence.

1) Data Extract

2) File Transfer

3) Import